# Mock of postForObject of RestTemplate returns null

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I am trying to mock postForObject but some how it returns me null

```
restTemplate.postForObject(someUrl, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Here is my mock code

```
when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn("SOME STR");
```

I had spent almost a day to debug this and not sure why its not working!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that mockito actually injects your mock `restTemplate` into the class that you are unit testing, if not correct the code to do so.

Try providing it like :

```
when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.any())).thenReturn("SOME STR");
```